# How can I automate installing eclipse with the same plugins and settings on multiple computers?

Tags: eclipse, windows, batch-file

I want to find a way to quickly install eclipse with the same plugins and settings on several different Windows 7 computers. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

There are no easy solutions, but the process itself is clearly automateable. One solution would be the use of the [p2 director application](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html). You have to download a single director installation - one is available from the [Buckminster download page](https://www.eclipse.org/buckminster/downloads.html), but from any Eclipse installation you can access this director application and use it to download all required software.

An alternative is the [Oomph project](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Installer), where you can define a model that describes what features do you want to install (among other things, such as default properties, source code to checkout), and it manages the download and installation automatically; and can also update the installation as well. One of my collegues like Oomph very much, but to tell the truth, my personal experience was that it was a bit raw (a few month ago).